# Objective C IOS class variable called "id"

Tags: objective-c

Can i call a class variable "id" (for example NSString *id)?
Everything seems to work, except that i cannot make [id release] in dealloc method. I'm creating instances of this class from a XML parser using object/key construct so i need this to be called id. I've tried [self.id release] and everthing works, except that the analyzer shows me a warning saying "Property returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count" and "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller". So i'm wondering if i'm doing something illegal. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

`id` in objective-c is a predefined type.  You should probably name it something different, like `idString`

It is the same thing as attempting to name a variable `int` or another objective-c keyword like `if`

Answer (score 2):

`id` is a keyword in objective-c. It's a weak type variable identifier, similar to `var` in javascript.

Comment: Actually, in ARC, id is `__strong` by default :) It also should be noted that you can't put just anything into an `id` and expect it to work.

Comment: weak type isn't the same as weak reference. This is a weak type. I expect I could have a weak referenced weak type: `(__weak id)`

Comment: I was making a bit of a joke. I'm just saything that your answer could use some clarification

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it.

- It's a meaningless name - the ID of *what*?
- It clashes with a language keyword and is bound to have some unwanted effects somewhere
- It hurts readability, people will have to wonder what you are referring to at any point in the code

Comment: yes, i know. I tried this because i'm bulding istances of this class by an xml parser(read from an external xml which i can't control), with set ojbect/keys construct. I have more than 30 variables. I think i will use a if([isEqualString:@"id"]) in the parser to change the name of this particular property. Thank you.

Comment: Actually (unless this has changed with Xcode 4.3, which I don't have yet), variable names and typedefs (of which `id` is one) exist in separate namespaces in Objective-C. I just saw an illuminating writeup about that recently, but I can't find it now.